# Can't set date on Android (ADB)

Tags: android, shell, date, set, adb

My phone is an old Motorola razr hd (xt925). Recently, the date and time changed without reason. So i root my phone, but i can't change date or time, it just doesn't work. Even in adb shell as root.

```
# toolbox date -s 20170209.000000
Thu Nov 24 04:07:01 ART 2016
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `date` help

```
usage: date [-u] [-r FILE] [-d DATE] [+DISPLAY_FORMAT] [-D SET_FORMAT] [SET]

Set/get the current date/time. With no SET shows the current date.

Default SET format is "MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]", that's (2 digits each)
month, day, hour (0-23), and minute. Optionally century, year, and second.
Also accepts "@UNIXTIME[.FRACTION]" as seconds since midnight Jan 1 1970.

-d  Show DATE instead of current time (convert date format)
-D  +FORMAT for SET or -d (instead of MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss])
-r  Use modification time of FILE instead of current date
-u  Use UTC instead of current timezone

+FORMAT specifies display format string using these escapes:

%% literal %             %n newline              %t tab
%S seconds (00-60)       %M minute (00-59)       %m month (01-12)
%H hour (0-23)           %I hour (01-12)         %p AM/PM
%y short year (00-99)    %Y year                 %C century
%a short weekday name    %A weekday name         %u day of week (1-7, 1=mon)
%b short month name      %B month name           %Z timezone name
%j day of year (001-366) %d day of month (01-31) %e day of month ( 1-31)
%s seconds past the Epoch

%U Week of year (0-53 start sunday)   %W Week of year (0-53 start monday)
%V Week of year (1-53 start monday, week < 4 days not part of this year)

%D = "%m/%d/%y"    %r = "%I : %M : %S %p"   %T = "%H:%M:%S"   %h = "%b"
%x locale date     %X locale time           %c locale date/time
```

pay attention to this

> Default SET format is "MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss]"

then, your command should be

```
date 0209000017
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using `toolbox date` - which still uses the `-s` parameter to set the date. Your answer is about the new `toybox date` and is irrelevant.

Comment: Even so, I ran that command (date 0209000017)but it did not work either.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MAC, I got the solution:

If you want to set date for 9th Feb 2017 Go for this 
adb shell "date -u 'date +0209000017'"

Use -u